# How to set "grunt --help" as the default task in a Gruntfile

Tags: gruntjs

I would like to make the output of "grunt --help" the default task for my Gruntfile.

I have tried something like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ':--help');
```

But that doesn't work.

Any ideas on how I can make the default task print the full help message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
grunt.registerTask('default', grunt.help.display)
```